# Is there any LBS like google which is allowed in China and have Android API?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-location, android-1.6-donut

We are developing a mobile application in Android for mobile and tablet. We use Android version 1.6.

In our application we use Google Maps API for displaying location details. One of our application deployment places is China. In china Google's LBS (location-based service) including Google Maps are blocked in China.

So we cannot use Google Maps or Google's LBS in China. Are there any LBS like Google allowed in China and have an Android API?

We welcome your suggestions and ideas.

Comment: mapapi@baidu.com is the email id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Baidu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baidu) provides map API for mobile devices including Android, iOS. The Android API is somewhat similar to Google's. But their [developer site](http://dev.baidu.com/wiki/imap/index.php) is only available in Chinese language.

Comment: Google Translate plugin will convert it into English very well.

Comment: In that site the contact details is also displayed in chinese.We does not know chinese and we use goog translator to covert it into english and we send email (mapapi@baidu.com) to them (baidu).Sometimes google translator is not accurate.So if any one know the contact details such as email,phone number,etc of baidu then please post it.It will very helpfull in our side.